# Does typing wine uninstall work? it did for me

Tags: wine

I had a problem removing a program and it's icons in wine .. I used regedit, deleted files in wine folder and applications folder... and finally just used wine uninstall and removed it from wine altogether.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The contents of your question looks like an answer and not explaining what is the problem that you are facing. Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506782/edit) your question and clearly mention your problem. If you have an answer to the question, you can answer it under the question.